# How to add elements in a list, list consists a hashmap (key value pair) in groovy

Tags: list, groovy, dictionary

I have added hashmap to a list

Here is my list which consists of three different hashmaps.

```
{504=1111.07, 502=969.64, 501=823.43, 503=680.2, 512=669.03, 505=647.0}
{504=235.18, 502=205.24, 501=174.29, 503=143.98, 512=141.61, 505=136.95}
{504=235.18, 502=205.24, 501=174.29, 503=143.98, 512=141.61, 505=136.95}
```

I want to add all values with key as 504

Ex: 1111.07+235.18+235.18

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def list = [
    [504:1111.07, 502:969.64, 501:823.43, 503:680.2, 512:669.03, 505:647.0], 
    [504:235.18, 502:205.24, 501:174.29, 503:143.98, 512:141.61, 505:136.95],
    [504:235.18, 502:205.24, 501:174.29, 503:143.98, 512:141.61, 505:136.95]
]

assert list.sum { it[504] } == 1581.43
```

should do.